# Is there anyway of unpacking a Python list and convert to int at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this snippet:

```py
s = "A 1 B 2"
a, a1, b, b1 = s.split()
a1 = int(a1)
b1 = int(b1)
```

I was wondering if there is anyway of unpacking and converting to `int` or anything else at the same time. I can also write the snippet as follows:

```
s = "A 1 B 2"
a, a1, b, b1 = (int(x) if i in (1, 3) else i, x for x in enumerate(s.split()))
```

But I wanted to know if there is a shorter version. Something like

```py
a, int(a1), b, int(b1) = s.split()
```

which would make something like this also possible:

```py
s = "A 1 B 2.3"
a, int(a1), b, float(b1) = s.split()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is your data and datatypes:

```py
# data and datatypes
t = 'a 1 2.4 b'
dtypes = [str, int, float, str]
```

```py
a, a1, b, b1 = [dtypes[i](n) for i, n in enumerate(t.split())]
```

Comment: Re: _"This is the shortest code you can get":_  I wouldn't use `enumerate` and access by index, but [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (and I also feel that we shouldn't construct a `list`), so I'd update the right hand side of your assignment to `(t(x) for t, x in zip(dtypes, s.split()))`.

Comment: here manfred edited the question. Also you should consider adding your answer to a separate answer instead of a comment so it can be accepted

Answer (score 0):

You could create a "universal" converter:

```
def converter(s):
    """Attempts to convert to int, float or returns a string"""
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            return s


s = "A 1 B 3.141"

a,b,c,d = map(converter, s.split())  # apply function to all splitted things

# print values and its types
print(a, b, c, d, *map(type, (a,b,c,d)))
```

Output:

```
A 1 B 3.141 <class 'str'> <class 'int'> <class 'str'> <class 'float'>
```

However:

This will perform at most 3 conversion attempts per list member, you need to have exactly 4 things in your string and all in all its not very reusable. If you plug in `'A B C D'` it will try 4 int conversion and 4 float conversions to get to 4 strings.

Can you do it? Yes. Should you? I have my doubts.

Comment: Did you know that exceptions are expensive in Python?